# filtro de registros por fecha - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy realizando un reporte que me traiga créditos que hayan sido cancelados antes de su fecha de vencimiento

este es mi query

```
SELECT
  bp.BPId
, bp.ContractNumber  AS [Numero de Prestamo]
, bp.MaturityDate    AS [Fecha de Vencimiento]
, bp.ValueDate       AS [Fecha de Cierre]

FROM Creditos bp

WHERE bp.Estado = 4
```

Este pequeño query me trae los creditos que fueron cancelados (estado 4 es Cancelado), pero hay algunos que fueron cancelados antes de su fecha de vencimiento

Entonces como puedo filtrar los creditos que el campo **Fecha de Cierre** sea mayor o igual a 6 meses al campo **Fecha de Vencimiento**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando dateAdd para sumarle 6 meses a la fecha de cierre.

```
SELECT
  bp.BPId
, bp.ContractNumber  AS [Numero de Prestamo]
, bp.MaturityDate    AS [Fecha de Vencimiento]
, bp.ValueDate       AS [Fecha de Cierre]

FROM Creditos bp

WHERE bp.Estado = 4
And
bp.MaturityDate >= DateAdd(month,6,bp.ValueDate);
```

[DateAdd Sql Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Funciono perfecto, Gracias